# Font awesome icons and toggling

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

Good afternoon,

I've added some font awesome icons to my website and they look great. I want to toggle between the fa-angle-up and fa-angle down when the user clicks accordion content.

This javascript is doing the job just fine:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that all other icons that have been inserted on the page within the  tag are also toggling to show the fa-angle- down when I click them. This one, for example, should not toggle:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
```

How can toggle only fa-angle icons without toggling other icons in  tags?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide Id to the specific icon element and carry out change in it not all i.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "a" ).toggle(function() {
  console.log( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
  $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-angle-down');  
}, function() {
  console.log( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down');
  $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-angle-up');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

> **Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]**
>
> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing a given substring.

which means you can select them only which has a 'fa-angle' string inside of class attribute as below.

$('i[class*="fa-angle"]').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code below:

```
$(function() {
 $('a').click(function() {
      $(this).find('[class^="fa-angle"]').toggleClass('fa-angle-down').toggleClass('fa-angle-up');
  });
 });
```